# iterate through all objects in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i am working on CrossWord application for Android.

I have a gridview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GridView gridView;
private Button button;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

static final String[] numbers = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
        "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
        "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
        "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
        "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                tv.setTag("1");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }
    });
}

public void onSubmitClick(View v){
    for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
         String s = adapter.getItem(i);
    }
}
```

xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="onSubmitClick">
    </Button>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonSubmit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:columnWidth="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What i want is to iterate through gridview and find textviews with tag1 ... but adapter.getItem returns only string ... any help ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can iterate over all children of a `GridView` (or any other `ViewGroup`) with `getChildAt()`:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < myGridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView child = (TextView) mGridView.getChildAt(i);
        // do stuff with child view
    }
```

Notice that sometimes a `GridView`'s child is another `ViewGroup`, so you may need to loop through *it's* children, etc.

---

However... a better way to do this might be to keep a separate `List` of "tagged" elements. You can simply add them to the list when tagged and iterate over the entire list.

Comment: it works but instead off ViewGroup i casted it to TextView because i was getting classcastexception :) thank you :) voted as correct answer ...

Comment: Ah, yea, you want to cast it to whatever the child view actually is. I'll edit the code to match.