# Android - Get all children of a GridLayout?

Tags: android, animation, grid-layout

How can I get all the children of a GridLayout? In my GridLayout, I'm adding views with `blahblah.addView(child)`, not through XML. The GridLayout is set out a bit like this:

`+++++++++    ++++++++++    ++++++++++
|ImageView|  |ImageView|   |ImageView|
|         |  |         |   |         |
++++++++++   ++++++++++    ++++++++++ 
[TextView]   [Textview]    [TextView]`

I need a button to play an animation on all the imageViews within the GridLayout. Don't worry, I already have that covered. So I need to do `child.startAnimation(anim)` on all the children of the GridLayout. How can I do this Programatically?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterate through all objects in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523860/iterate-through-all-objects-in-gridview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check docs for [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) (and samples there) and you will find `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` methods. Note that child can be `ViewGroup` too, so you should use recurrency to get that processed correctly.

Answer (score 12):

here is a sample code.

```
GridLayout mlayout;
int count = mlayout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0 ; i <count ; i++){
    View child = mlayout.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: who is downgraing answers, whats wrong with this code ?? can you please care to explain.

Comment: always put some explanation while posting answer, it is very easy to understand people who are new in programming or not able to get by looking at code only.